# What is the name of these "offset" nibs and pens?

Tags: calligraphy, tool-identification

I was looking into pen nib preventative maintenance and found a couple of pictures that I didn't understand. The first we see the nib on top is not the same as the rest as it has a crooked body.

[image: some pen nibs]

<sup>Image from [linktoink.wordpress.com](https://linktoink.wordpress.com/2010/08/19/6-simple-ways-to-care-for-your-calligraphy-nibs/)</sup>

Then you have this pen which look like you get the same effect as the nib but the pen is specialized and normal nibs are used. This image was part of a "pointed pen" image. Searching for that did not help. So I know it is called something else.

[image: Special pen]

<sup>Image from [Reddit.com](https://www.reddit.com/r/Calligraphy/comments/3ektam/pointed_pen_practice/)</sup>

What are these called and what are they used for? Is this something that is easy to handle for some?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is called an **Oblique Calligraphy Pen**. It is used because it makes it much easier to hold the nib pointing in angles that are otherwise very hard to achieve if you're right handed (oblique angles):

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Half answer?  The nib in question in an "oblique nib' vs. a straight nib in an oblique holder.

I find the oblique nib in a straight holder less mechanical than the other, with one less joint. i.e.  one less place to provide wear and a loose connection. ( It's what I was trained with and is just physically tighter.)

If you can still find them, buy them ...

Answer (score 2):

The two images in the original question are both images of pointed pen nibs. Within "pointed pens" there are variations - the top image is an oblique nib while the bottom image is an oblique pen - both are great for right handed calligraphers (and personally, my favorite type of pen for calligraphy!) - they are more comfortable to grip when doing long stretches of calligraphy.